# What is the best way to exhibit extra large sets, like Taj Mahal?

Tags: storage, safety, preservation

Before buying our dream set (Taj Mahal) we are wondering with my Wife how to exhibit it properly? The set is much larger than any other construction we have (23.03x19.29x7.48 inches) and will not fit any furniture we used before for exposition.

We are wondering, what would be the best way to exhibit such large sets, so that they are simultaneously visible and safe? Should one use large glass display cases or some other solutions? I would be grateful for photos of inspiration. Should we buy some generic furniture, or custom made, or could we make it ourselves?

Certainly we would like to protect it against dust. White bricks yellows when exposed to UV light for a long period of time, at least those old one, I don't have long enough experience with the newer ones. Is the Taj Mahal prone to yellowing?

Comment: This looks like one of those times when you have too much LEGO. And I find it more (space wise) efficient to keep my big sets disassembled. There's a ton of benefits apart from being able to show off.

Comment: Hi Piotr and welcome to Bricks.SE! I took the liberty to edit your question, as here all questions are expected to have an objectively true answer - and "how do you do X" can be answered in as many ways as there are answerers. Whereas asking for the best way is a bit more unambiguous, especially since you have provided the space of possible answers and your preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't own the set in question and I'm not affiliated with anyone selling products mentioned below.</sub>

Searching in [Google for "lego taj mahal acrylic cover"](https://www.google.com/search?q=lego%20taj%20mahal%20acrylic%20cover&tbm=isch) reveals a staggering selection of acrylic dust covers clearly intended for this specific model. Judging by the supply side I can only conclude that the demand side of the market must be equally large then. Which means many people use such a cover to both display and protect their Taj Mahal, just like you wish to do.

Comment: The Taj Mahal model has a specific issue, in that the tall minarets are not very stable and are close to the four corners of the model. A cover that protects them from being knocked accidentally would be a good idea, aside from any other issues displaying large models in general.

Comment: Just my observation. I read that acrylic could be UV Filtering or UV Transmitting and none of 5 or so covers I've checked tell which version is being used.